# shuffle matrix element in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a martix and want to shuffle element of it .

```
x=[1 2 5 4 6 ]
```

after shuffle(something like this)

```
x=[2 4 6 5 1]
```

is matlab has function for it  ? 
**in php array_shuffle** do this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. obtain shuffled indices using `randperm`

   ```
   idx = randperm(length(x));
   ```
2. use indices to obtain shuffled vector

   `xperm = x(idx);`

Comment: How do we shuffle n*n matrix? One way is to create idx row by row: first row with randperm(n), second row with n+randperm(n), third row with 2n+randperm(n), and so forth.. and then use the indices. Is this correct? Is there a better way? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

As an alternate to `randperm`, you can also use [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) from the statistics toolbox.

> `y = randsample(n,k)` returns a `k`-by-`1` vector `y` of values sampled uniformly at random, without replacement, from the integers `1` to `n`.

Note that it is "without replacement" (by default). So if you set `k` as `length(x)`, it is equivalent to doing a random shuffle of the vector. For example:

```
x = 1:5;
randsample(x,length(x))
%ans = 
%       4     5     3     1     2
```

I like this more than `randperm`, because it is easily extensible to different uses. For example, to draw 3 elements from `x` at random (like drawing from a bucket with finite items), you do `randsample(x,3)`. Likewise, if you wish to draw 3 numbers, where the alphabet is made up of the elements of `x`, but allow for repetitions, you do `randsample(x,3,true)`.