# How to randomly fill a 1x5 array with the numbers from 1 to 5 without repeating a number?

Tags: arrays, matlab, random

I'm looking to fill a 1x5 array with the numbers from 1 to 5, but I don't want to repeat a number.

I've tried this, which allows numbers to repeat:

```
r = randi([1,5],5,1)
```

What I'm looking for is something that will generate ex. [5 2 3 1 4] randomly. Is there a function in Matlab that will allow me to do so?

Comment: Looks like http://stackoverflow.com/a/13259950/2665510 is your exact answer

Comment: @wilkesybear Thank you! Sorry for the redundancy fo the question--didn't realize that what I was looking for was called "shuffling".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`randperm`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html). It does exactly what you want.

```
r = randperm(5)
```

From the documentation:

> `p = randperm(n)` returns a row vector containing a random permutation
>   of the integers from 1 to n inclusive

You can also check out [`randsample`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) if you have the [statistic toolbox](http://se.mathworks.com/products/statistics/).